# pyqtgraph live data from a CMOS camera

Tags: python, memory, live, pyqtgraph

I am trying to plot live data that is streamed from a CMOS camera in python. As a little side note: I want to use this to stabilize the pointing of a laser in the lab.
I am using ImageItem from the pyqtgraph module and my script is basically a modification of the ImageItem example (see below).

However when I execute the script I immediately get a delay of about 3 seconds and the RAM memory increases until the process gets killed. The resolution of the camera is 3672x5496 pixel which is quiet high and it seems like the pictures are queuing up until it is out of memory (my interpretation of the problem).

I tried to clear the ImageItem module every time when it gets updated but it does not change anything.

What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible to get this working live and without running out of memory with this resolution? I am already happy with about 1-2 frames per seconds.

```
## Add path to library (just for examples; you do not need this)
#import initExample

from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
import pyqtgraph.ptime as ptime
import gxipy as gx
import sys



## Check for connected devices
device_manager = gx.DeviceManager()
dev_num, dev_info_list = device_manager.update_device_list()
if dev_num == 0:
    sys.exit(1)

## Connect to the camera
strSN = dev_info_list[0].get("sn")
cam = device_manager.open_device_by_sn(strSN)
## start the data stream
cam.stream_on()

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
## Create window with GraphicsView widget
win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
win.show()  ## show widget alone in its own window
win.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: ImageItem')
view = win.addViewBox()
## lock the aspect ratio so pixels are always square
view.setAspectLocked(True)

## Create image item
img = pg.ImageItem(border='w')
view.addItem(img)

## Set initial view bounds
view.setRange(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 3672, 5496))

## Create random image

updateTime = ptime.time()

def updateData():
    global img, i, updateTime

    ## Get a new image from the camera
    raw_image = cam.data_stream[0].get_image()
    data = raw_image.get_numpy_array()
    if data is None:
        sys.exit(1)

    ## Display the image
    img.setImage(data)

    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1, updateData)


updateData()

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()

    cam.stream_off()
    cam.close_device()
```